# Develop / Debug / Compile Java programs using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: java, visual-studio, debugging, compilation, visual-studio-2017

**Is there any way to manage/debug/compile Java projects using [Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/whatsnew/)?**

I think this is possible in the old versions of Visual Studio like Visual Studio 2010, but the version I'm currently using is 2017.

This is possible using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), but that's not what I want.

I want to develop Java programs using [Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/whatsnew/) if this is possible.

Any help to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to manage/debug/compile Java projects using Visual Studio 2017?

I am afraid Not.

Since you are using Visual Studio **2017**, there is no such extension to support Visual Studio 2017 currently.

[Java Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.JavaLanguageSupport) works with Visual Studio 2010-2015 except 2017.

Even if we can use [some techniques to compile java with Visual Studio](https://improve.dk/compiling-java-in-visual-studio/), we still could not debug it currently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this information, please update your answer if any updates are made enabling me to develop JAVA programs in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @HusamEbish, OK, I will and let you know it ASAP :).

Answer (score 0):

You can manage/debug/compile Java projects using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

You can follow the steps [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java)